# Ask the definition of complete statistic

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Completeness is a property of a family of probability distributions, not of a particular distribution. In the textbook, I see that a binomial family is a complete statistic. Here, the object of completeness is a family distributions. But I also see that given a iid uniform $(0, \theta)$ observations, $T(X)=\max_i X_i$ is a complete statistic. This goes back to my familiar feeling, such as a complete statistic could be max, min, sum, order statistic, etc in the section of sufficient statistics.

However, in the first example, we directly say a binomial family is a complete statistic.

They make me very confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying 'a binomial family is a complete statistic' makes no sense.

What we can say is that a binomial family of distributions $\{\text{Binomial}(n,\theta):\theta \in [0,1]\}$ is complete. Here the family of distributions is indexed by the parameter $\theta$.

This means that if $X\sim \text{Binomial}(n,\theta)$, then $\operatorname E_{\theta}[g(X)]=0$ implies $g(X)=0$ almost surely for any (measurable) function $g$.

Comment: Thank you. I think I understand. $X$ can always be seen a sufficient statistics, since the data itself is absolutely sufficient. Then given a binomial family of distributions,  $X$, a sufficient statistics per se, is also complete. But this has a follow-up question. $\Sigma X_i$ is also complete in binomial distribution. So, both $X$ and  $\Sigma X_i$ are complete?

Comment: What are the $X_i$'s?

Comment: Binomial belongs to exponential family. Then by theorem, $\Sigma X_i$ is sufficient, and also complete, if $\theta$ has an interval density,

Comment: You don't answer my question. If $X_i$'s are i.i.d Bernoulli$(\theta)$, then $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is a complete sufficient statistic having a Binomial$(n,\theta)$ distribution. This is equivalent to saying that if $X\sim \text{Bin}(n,\theta)$, then $X$ is a complete sufficient statistic for $\theta$.